# Normalizr - for what purpose "result" prop is placed in the output?

Tags: javascript, normalizr

So, typically, when we create normalized entity shape by using func `normalize(originalData, someShape)` - we gets an object on the output with form like:

`{ entities: {...}, result: main_entities_id }`

And question is - why we need the second `result` prop in the normalized object? What is the reason to place it here by creators of `normalizr`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the *normalized* form of the input data.

For example:

- If your input data is a single entity, the result will be the ID of that entity.
- If your input data has shape `[ entity1, entity2 ]`, the result will be an array of the IDs for those entities, `[ '1', '2' ]`.